# date cannot be cast to fit into JDateChooser

Tags: netbeans

Hello Guys I am facing problem with casting date that I retrieve from Ms access DB to JDateChooser, but  a message appear to me telling  java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.util.Date..

```
String sql="select * from Patient where PatientID=?";    try{
       ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
       ps.setString(1, txt_PID.getText());
       rs=ps.executeQuery();
       if(rs.next()){
        //   String add1=rs.getString("PatientID");
          // txt_PID.setText(add1);
            String add2=rs.getString("PatientName");
           txt_PName.setText(add2);
            String add3=rs.getString("PatientGender");
           cmb_PGender.setSelectedItem(add3);
            String add4=rs.getString("PatientAge");
           txt_PAge.setText(add4);
            String add5=rs.getString("PatientType");
           cmb_PType.setSelectedItem(add5);
            String add6=rs.getString("PatientGSM");
           txt_PGsm.setText(add6);
           String add7=rs.getString("Patient_Maj_Jop");
           txt_major_Jop.setText(add7);

           DateFormat formatter ;
            Date  date1; 
           String add8=rs.getString("DateOfReg"); 
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");   
            date1 = (Date)formatter.parse(add8); 
            dch_Date.setDate(date1);


           table_PatuentReg.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));  
       }    }catch(Exception e){    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());

   }
    if(txt_PID.getText().equals("")){
           Update_Table();
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at date1 variable, I'm guessing you might be using java.sql.Date? Check you are indeed using java.util.Date.

Show us your import statements.

The problem is with this line because DateFormatter is returning you an instance of java.util.Date and you are trying to cast it to a java.sql.Date which it isn't.

```
            date1 = (Date)formatter.parse(add8);
```

Easy fix is to import java.util.Date instead. I don't see there is a need for you to use java.sql.Date as you are not fetching Date SQL colum, are you?

Comment: what is the problem, because I know little with programming